# R remove duplicated columns

Tags: r, unique

I have data like this

```
     X3    X4    X5    X6     X7   X24   X25   X26    X39    X40    X41    X54    X55    X56    X69    X70    X71
1 step1 step2 step3 step4 step10 step2 step3 step4 step10 step10 step10 step10 step10 step10 step10 step10 step10
```

And I want remove duplicated columns. So desired output is

```
  X3    X4    X5    X6     X7
1 step1 step2 step3 step4 step10
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 df[!duplicated(as.list(df))]
     X3    X4    X5    X6     X7
1 step1 step2 step3 step4 step10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df <- read.table(text = "X3    X4    X5    X6     X7   X24   X25   X26    X39    X40    X41    X54    X55    X56    X69    X70    X71
1 step1 step2 step3 step4 step10 step2 step3 step4 step10 step10 step10 step10 step10 step10 step10 step10 step10",
                 header = TRUE)

df[!duplicated(lapply(df, summary))]
#Output
#     X3    X4    X5    X6     X7
#1 step1 step2 step3 step4 step10
```

Comment: In my data set the output of your code is
     X3
1 step1